# One single onComplete callback for the last of two functions to execute

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I have two functions that run at the same time and I want a callback to execute just once when the last one finishes.

```
function gotoPage () {
  //only call this once for the last one
}
app.update(gotoPage);
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gotoPage);
```

I realise that I could nest them for sequential execution but I'd prefer not to for performance reasons.
Is there a neat trick to do this efficiently?

Comment: why you dont use promise instead ?

Comment: I haven't looked inot Promise please could you elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with Promises:

```
Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => app.update(resolve)),
    new Promise(resolve => geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve)),
]).then(() => gotoPage());
```

You can read up on Promise here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: I'm writing for a Cordova app and targeting potentially pre-ES6 mobile browsers. How would this degrade?

Comment: If you go on MDN and look up the reference for the Promise class, then you can see the exact browser compatibility; you can also check http://caniuse.com . AFAIK promises are pretty well supported, from Edge onwards; not in IE though. You can check if polyfills exist for olders browsers.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer however I didn't specify in the question that my target browsers are old so I actually can't use this. Thank you though, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Quick trick is to use a variable that counts how many functions got finished

```
var i = 0;

function gotoPage () {
   i++;

   if(i == requiredNumber) {
      // execute stuff

   } else { // some is pending }

  //only call this once for the last one
}
app.update(gotoPage);
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gotoPage);
```

Comment: why make things complicated while he can use promise to achieve his end goal in a clean way ?

Comment: Promise is surely great (for those who understand it properly). This is just a quick dirty trick to get things work

Comment: Please could you show an example of how this could be achieved with promise?

Comment: I will probably use something along the line of this approach due to older target browsers.